# Hands-On Machine Learning Code not working in Jupyter, but works on Google. Why?

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm working on interpreting code in the book Hands-On Machine Learning with Sci-Kit Learn, Keras & Tensorflow, but came across an issue with the code in the NLP section. The author changed some of the code in a github repository for the book:https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/16_nlp_with_rnns_and_attention.ipynb#scrollTo=kYZbDNAiilzL. When opening the code in Google Collab, it works just fine, but when I try to use the same code in Jupyter notebooks, I get the following errors:

```
"OutOfRangeError:  End of sequence
 [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at C:\Users\bryan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] 
 [Op:__inference_distributed_function_10917]

 Function call stack:
 distributed_function
```

and

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'"
```

I'm not sure I understand the error and why it would work in Google Collab and not Jupyter. Any ideas?

Comment: What part of the code raises this error?

Comment: Anyway, I guess that the first thing that you should do on your troubleshooting is verify if you've got the same python and libs version and the same data locally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because TensorFlow version.

Colab now uses TF 2.2 by default. Maybe your local machine is still 2.0.